# Datatype of Hour in oracle

Tags: oracle10g

When we use the query like this in oracle to get the the total number of hours in round figure,

```
hours= select round(out_time-in_time)*24 from table_name;
```

what is the datatype of hours here?
`out_time` and `in_time` are column names

Comment: Why don't you describe the table yourself and find out?

Comment: I want to access it as an integer value! how can i do that??

Comment: We don't know what datatype your columns are! You need to tell us what you have before anyone will be able to effectively help you get to where you want to be.

Comment: My datatype for the column is date! I want to keep it as date only.

Comment: The result is an integer. What problem are you having with that? Is Java throwing an error, or is the result not what you are expecting?

Comment: Yeah. Result is not what i am expecting. Are you sure that its an integer datatype? coz its not working :(

Comment: Why don't you describe what result you get, and what result you expect?

Comment: for eg, When i fire that query on oracle, I am getting 35 hours as expected. But when i try to query in java using resultset into an integer variable, ders no value coming into it. It simply shows its initialized value. I.e, 0 n not 35

Comment: Sounds like showing the java code would be useful then.

Answer (score 0):

You can take [NUMBER](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements001.htm) as the datatype in your case.

EDIT:- This will return you an integer

```
select 24 * round((to_date('2013-07-07 22:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi') 
         - to_date('2013-07-07 19:30', 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi'))) diff_hours 
   from table_name;
```

Comment: No, you can't; in order to do this in the manner specified by the OP it can _only_ be a number...

Comment: I want to access it as an integer value! how can i do that??

Comment: @ASK:- If it is a newly created table then define both the column names as NUMBER and if it is an existing table with existing columns then please tell the datatype of both the columns!!!

Comment: i am not storing it in table. Directly accessing it in java using ResultSet. I am using integer variable for getting that value from resultset. But its not working

Comment: What is the datatype of the colums which you have defined for the column in your table?

Comment: datatype for both columns is date. When i fire the same query on oracle directly, i am getting correct answer in hours and that also round figure as i wanted. But i am not sure what its datatype is??

Comment: @ASK:-Can you provide one sample date which is stored in your table for these columns???

Comment: Yes. eg., 25-AUG-2013 12:00:00

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a datatype called "INTERVAL" will suit you. It's called:

```
INTERVAL DAY [(day_precision)] TO SECOND
Stores a period of time in days, hours, minutes, and seconds
```

Interval is something that can we added (or substrated) to a DATE or TIMESTAMP.

see: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements001.htm